# Django Apache mod_wsgi co existing with Wordpress cannot establish database connection

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, database-connection, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Django app on a Centos server that has Apache and Wordpress.
The app is working with the django build in development server with no problem but when i try to deploy with mod_wsgi i get an error: Error establishing a database connection.My guess is that it has something to do with the configuration file and it tries to run the app using wordpress and not mod_wsgi that's why i get this wordpress error but i've been trying and searching how to fix this and i've come to no solution.

My configuration files are 2 seperate files in conf.d:

django.conf:

```
Alias /static/ /root/mass_update/static/


<Directory /root/mass_update/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>



WSGIScriptAlias /mass_update /root/mass_update/dashboard/wsgi.py


<Directory /root/mass_update/dashboard>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Directory>

#WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mass_update/:/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages

WSGIDaemonProcess mass_update  python-path=/root/mass_update:/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mass_update
```

idash.conf(wordpress):

```
<VirtualHost 172.31.128.20:80>
#       ServerAlias test

        DocumentRoot /var/www/idash
        ServerName idash.test.gr
        <Directory /var/www/idash>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for dashboard project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] 


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mass_update',
    'smart_selects',
    'widget_tweaks',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dashboard.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dashboard.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'test',
    'PASSWORD': 'tes',
    'HOST': 'host_ip',
    'PORT':'host_port',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Django connects to oracleDB.
I also used '/' as WSGIScript Alias and get a 500 error guessing there is a conflict with wordpress running at '/'
I've tried with many changes on configuration file with no luck.
Does anyone have any suggestions what am i missing and what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! it seems that mysql-community removed.And had to reinstall it.
After installing mysql everything worked.